# Error messages in joomla site after installing sobipro

Tags: joomla-3.x

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplicationSite::getMenu() should not be called statically in /var/www/sobipro/components/com_sobipro/router.php on line 246

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplicationCms::getMenu() should not be called statically in /var/www/sobipro/libraries/cms/application/site.php on line 279

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /var/www/sobipro/components/com_sobipro/router.php on line 246

Comment: These are just warnings. You should check the `error.log` file for error leading to blank page. Please update your answer with this error.

Comment: Strict errors are not a big issue. You shuld simply disable strict error reporting in your php.ini

Answer (score 1):

These messages just indicates that sobipro code is not following full php coding specifications.

There will not be any major issue due to these notice indicators.

For hiding these messages, there is a configuration setting available in Joomla global configuration, under server section, named **Error Reporting**, set this to "**System-Default**".

Answer (score 1):

find this solution.

install php5-xsl.

command : sudo apt-get install php5-xsl

it's work perfectly.

Thanks.